# NuGet.exe : File contains corrupted data

Tags: nuget

When trying to push a nuget package I get:

> NuGet.exe : File contains corrupted data. At line:1 char:6
>   + nuget <<<<  push .\src\Ext.Direct.Mvc\Ext.Direct.Mvc.nuspec
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (File contains corrupted data.:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

I have the latest update of nuget. I followed the [guide](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) to publish a project to nuget. But at the

```
NuGet Push YourPackage.nupkg
```

I get the error. Is this maybe because of the dots in the folder/file name?

Answer (score 0):

I used an already existing name for the package. Apparently, this will give this cryptic error message when trying to push from the console.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little old but it helped me to debug the issue by adding

**-Verbosity detailed**

at the end of the command